# Cannot find tREST_request and tREST_response components in Talend for Data Integration v 7.3.1.20200219_1130

Tags: talend

I'm using Talend for Data Integration v 7.3.1.20200219_1130 and I want to use tREST_request and tREST_response as server side in order to convert an Excel file to XML file.
My problem is that I cannot find both components in ESB section, as described in Talend documentation, I looked also in "Palette Settings", there's only tRESTClient.
I'm wondering if this is a version problem (those components are omitted in this version) or those components are not avaible in free version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download Talend Open Studio for ESB in order to get those components.
I don't know why, but this version is not available anymore on talend website. You have to go to sourceforge to find it.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/talendesb/

With Talend Open Studio for ESB you can develop job to provide services (through tRestRequest/tRestResponse components, are SOAP components), as well as developing classic Talend Data Integration jobs.

Comment: I downloaded it and found both components i need, Thank you ^^ !